# Logback & SLF4J Writing to multiple files using the MDCFilter

Tags: spring, logback, slf4j, mdc

I have a spring project with these packages:

- core
- scheduledJobs
- web
- jms

Most of the logic is in the core package which is used by the other three packages. The other three packages do not use each others code.

I need to have 2 log files:

- First log file should contain all log entries associated with scheduled jobs.

  - All log entries from the scheduledJobs package.
  - If I call a function from the core package from a function located in the scheduledJobs package then this entry should be only in this log file.
- Second log file should contain every log entry **except** log entries that should go into the first log file.

**The problem**
I can see the following information in the logback debug log:

```
[10/23/23 16:38:53:064 UTC] 0000008e SystemOut     O   16:38:53,064 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler - Ignoring unknown property [turboFilter] in [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
```

I can see the MDC values in logs but filtering does not work, both log files have all the log entries.

My logback file:

```
<!-- LOCAL -->
<configuration>
    <property name="APP.NAME" scope="context" value="App"/>
    <property name="APP.LOG.PATH" scope="context" value="logs/APP"/>

    <appender name="FILE.APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${APP.LOG.PATH}/${APP.NAME}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${APP.LOG.PATH}/${APP.NAME}%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.MDCFilter">
            <MDCKey>specialLogger</MDCKey>
            <Value>QUARTZ</Value>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>ACCEPT</OnMismatch>
        </turboFilter>

        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} [%X{correlationId}] [%X{specialLogger}] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE.APPENDER.QUARTZ" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${APP.LOG.PATH}/${APP.NAME}_QUARTZ.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${APP.LOG.PATH}/${APP.NAME}_QUARTZ%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.MDCFilter">
            <MDCKey>specialLogger</MDCKey>
            <Value>QUARTZ</Value>
            <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
        </turboFilter>

        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} [%X{correlationId}] [%X{specialLogger}] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE.APPENDER" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE.APPENDER.QUARTZ" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Dependencies:

- logback-classic: 1.3.5
- logback-core: 1.3.5
- org.slf4j: 2.0.6

EDIT:
I also tried logging only to the "FILE.APPENDER.QUARTZ" which should only log entries based on the scheduledJobs filter. It contained all log entries anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
It isn't possible to use turboFilters for this functionality.
Instead I have to use a custom standard filter.

My logback file:

```
<!-- LOCAL -->
<configuration debug="true">
    <property name="APP.NAME" scope="context" value="PdfGen"/>
    <property name="APP.LOG.PATH" scope="context" value="logs/APP"/>

    <appender name="FILE.APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${APP.LOG.PATH}/${APP.NAME}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${APP.LOG.PATH}/${APP.NAME}%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <filter class="<package_path>.MDCFilterRegular">
            <MDCKey>specialLogger</MDCKey>
            <Value>QUARTZ</Value>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>ACCEPT</OnMismatch>
        </filter>

        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} [%X{uniqueNumber}] [%X{correlationId}] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE.APPENDER.QUARTZ" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${APP.LOG.PATH}/${APP.NAME}_QUARTZ.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${APP.LOG.PATH}/${APP.NAME}_QUARTZ%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <filter class="<package_path>.MDCFilterRegular">
            <MDCKey>specialLogger</MDCKey>
            <Value>QUARTZ</Value>
            <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
        </filter>

        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} [%X{uniqueNumber}] [%X{correlationId}] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE.APPENDER.QUARTZ" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE.APPENDER" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

The custom filter:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.filter.AbstractMatcherFilter;
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.FilterReply;

public class MDCFilterRegular extends AbstractMatcherFilter<ILoggingEvent> {
    String MDCKey;
    String Value;

    public MDCFilterRegular() {
    }

    public void start() {
        if (this.MDCKey != null && this.Value != null) {
            super.start();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(ILoggingEvent event) {
        if(!event.getMDCPropertyMap().containsKey(this.MDCKey)) {
            return this.onMismatch;
        }

        return event.getMDCPropertyMap().get(this.MDCKey).equals(Value) ? this.onMatch : this.onMismatch;
    }

    public String getMDCKey() {
        return MDCKey;
    }

    public void setMDCKey(String MDCKey) {
        this.MDCKey = MDCKey;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return Value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```